# Duplicate CSS Declarations Stripped By Browser(s)?

Tags: php, css, dynamic

I have a PHP application that I must dynamically generate a stylesheet for. The stylesheet has a `.php` file extension, but I set the `Content-Type` of the file to `text/css` via the `header` function (PHP), and then create properly formed CSS to suit my purpose and include this stylesheet in my page.

The issue I'm seeing is that when I view the CSS file through whatever browser tool I choose - be it Firebug, Chrome Dev Tools or IE Dev Tools, certain class declarations are missing (and it is evident as what is rendered by the browser - those classes don't exist).  When I check the raw output of the file (as in, put the address of the PHP CSS file in the browser to view the raw text), the missing class declarations are indeed there.

What's missing is usually a second (or nth) class that specifies the same `background-color` value, but different class name.

Here's a specific example:

In the raw output, I have these two classes:

```
#draft-board div.pick.RB{
  background-color: #FFCC66;
}

#draft-board div.pick.1B {
  background-color: #FFCC66;
}
```

But in the browser, it only sees:

```
#draft-board div.pick.RB{
  background-color: #FFCC66;
}
```

Why is this?

Here's a public example page:
http://www.phpdraft.com/public_draft.php?action=draftBoard&did=9

(and here's the raw CSS output for that page:)
http://www.phpdraft.com/css/draft_board_dynamic_styles.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue: CSS class names cannot start with a digit, hence the reason why all three browsers were not recognizing the CSS - they were properly following CSS while I was not!

Comment: CSS class names can start with a digit, but only as escaped by [CSS syntax rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#characters). For example, the class name `1B` would have to be written as `\31 B`. This is of course best avoided, if you can change class names.

Comment: Thank you for that specification - I did see that afterwards. I fixed the issue by simply adding a few entries that map to the originals and prefixed an `x` before them, so the class is actually `x1B`.